# Receive logical value if a variable exist

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if a variable exist in the dom and receive a true false answer.

I try this command:

```
document.body.contains(document.querySelectorAll('div.grid'))
```

but it is not working

any idea how can I change to have the right option?

Comment: DOM does not have any variables at all. You might wanna check if DOM element exists. @Rubydesic 's answer got your back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const containsElement = document.querySelectorAll('div.grid').length !== 0
```

Comment: or `document.querySelector('div.grid') != null`

Comment: `!!document.querySelector('div.grid')` for the cowboys out there